# Show message if string not found in memo

Tags: string, delphi, search, integer

```
procedure TForm1.bFAT1Click(sender: TObject);
    var
     FAT: Integer;
    begin
       for FAT := 0 to memo1.lines.Count - 1 do
        begin
          if AnsiContainsStr(memo1.lines[FAT], 'Olive Oil') then
          begin
          ShowMessage('Olive Oil exist!');
          end;
        end;
     // But  how to show message if integer is empty?        
    end;
```

I want to do something if no line contains 'Olive Oil'. How to do it?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. Could you check if it still matches your intent?

Comment: I suggest you to step away from the computer for a couple of minutes and think about the following: **Found** result = at least one line contains given substing, **`not` Found** result = ... (exercise)

Comment: @bummi: that does an exact match while the code in the question uses `AnsiContainsStr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an `Exit` statement to leave the procedure as soon as you found a matching element. That way, when you reach the end of the procedure, you know that you have not found a matching element:

```
for FAT := 0 to memo1.lines.Count - 1 do
begin
  if AnsiContainsStr(memo1.lines[FAT], 'Olive Oil') then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Olive Oil exist!')
    Exit;  // we can stop here since we found it       
  end;
end;

// we only come here if no line contained 'Olive Oil' (because of the EXIT)
ShowMessage('Olive Oil does not exist!');
```

**Edit**: (inspired by @David) It is good practice to separate your logic from the UI / display (for example ShowMessage). To do that you can define a function like this:

```
function IndexOfLineContaining(const Text : String; Lines : TStrings) : Integer;
begin
  for Result := 0 to Lines.Count - 1 do
    if AnsiContainsStr(Lines[Result], Text) then 
      Exit;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

On top of that you could easily define a boolean function:

```
function HasLineContaining(const Text : String; Lines : TStrings) : Boolean;
begin
  Result := (IndexOfLineContaining(Text, Lines) > -1);
end;
```

and use that to do your message display:

```
if HasLineContaining('Olive Oil', Memo1.Lines) then
  ShowMessage ('foo')
else
  ShowMessage ('bar');
```

*I suggest that you work a bit on your terminology to make your questions clearer. An integer cannot be empty and the sentence " do something if [FAT] do not found 'Olive Oil'." with `FAT` being an integer does not make any sense.*

Comment: It would be better to show how to separate the search from the message showing. So an IndexOfContains function would be good.

Comment: @jpfollenius:  Not quite sure the answer matches the question title, which doesn't seem to be restricted to Olive being on the same line as Oil?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you're right, I tried to improve the answer in this direction.

Comment: :( I am so sorry all for the messy term. I am very glad that all of you are helpful hands. My solution is using @jpfollenius code (the first code is causing loop, but second working great). It's doing exactly like i wanted. I a very happy ^-^. GBU ALL. - countdown to JC's b'day -